# Reporting Services expression gives error in some circumstances

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am getting an error when computing averages in summary line of a report.  My expression looks like this:

```
=IIF(SUM(Fields!column3.Value) > 0, Format(DateAdd("s", (SUM(Fields!column4.Value) / SUM(Fields!column3.Value)), "00:00:00"), "HH:mm:ss"), "-")
```

(sorry for the super long line)

The expression works fine when the data looks something like this:

```
8311    87  0   0
8311    41  0   0
8311    80  0   0
8311    136   1   136
```

The idea is that column 3 is a 1 if column 2 is over 120, otherwise it is 0.  Column 4 has value greater than 0 only if column 2 is greater that 120, in which case it is the same value as column 2.  In this way, for the summary line of this group in reporting services, I am able determine the total number of rows that are greater than 120 (by using SUM on column 3).  In the same way, I can determine the total number of the values in column 2 that are greater than 120 by summing column 4.  From there, it should be a simple matter of dividing column 4 by column 3 to determine the average of column 2 values that are over 120.

Once I get the average, I want to convert it to a time string (e.g., "00:02:16").  If there is no value (that is, no column 2 values over 120 in the group, I want to display a "-".

This logic appears to work in cases with column 2 has values over 120.  However, when column 3 and 4 are 0, like the below:

```
8310    108 0   0
```

the expression gives the dreaded #Error result when running the report.  I am assuming that this is a divide by zero error, so I threw the IIF in the expression to check that the denominator in my average calculation is > 0.

Sadly, #Error persists for those groups that have 0's in columns 3 and 4.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The iif in SSRS is the same as the Visual Basic IIF: it evaluates all branches, and if any portion generates an error, the entire function throws an error.

Two common work-arounds:

- Use embedded code in the report,
- Use a second IIF that will save your function from ever dividing by zero.

The second option:
Replace:

```
=IIF(SUM(Fields!column3.Value) > 0, Format(DateAdd("s", (SUM(Fields!column4.Value) / SUM(Fields!column3.Value)), "00:00:00"), "HH:mm:ss"), "-")
```

with

```
=IIF(SUM(Fields!column3.Value) > 0, Format(DateAdd("s", (SUM(Fields!column4.Value) / IIF(SUM(Fields!column3.Value)>0,SUM(Fields!column3.Value),1)), "00:00:00"), "HH:mm:ss"), "-")
```

(I think I got the right number of parens...)

Many examples of embedded code to handle divide by zero are around as well, here's one.
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/is/sqlreportingservices/thread/b8e0730b-da60-49a8-8613-2309ff1a2c90