# #Error shown in RDLC Report

Tags: c#, winforms, rdlc

I am trying to do calculation by using expression.

In fact I have the formula to validate whether the report items that used to calculate is 0, this is because if both report items is **0**, they **not allowed to divided**. So if both of the report items is 0, then 0.00 will be assigned to the column instead of process the calculation.

This is my expression which still show #**Error** in the report column even I have do IIf:

```
=IIf((ReportItems!TotalQty.Value = "0.000" And ReportItems!Textbox40.Value = "0.000"),  ReportItems!Textbox6.Value="0.00", FormatNumber((ReportItems!TotalQty.Value / ReportItems!Textbox40.Value * 100), 2))
```

[image]

***ReportItems!Textbox40.value is Grandtotal for TotalQty**

Do anyone know any way to correct this error.

Please help and guide. Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reporting Services expression gives error in some circumstances](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5344117/reporting-services-expression-gives-error-in-some-circumstances)

Comment: I think you have to remove ReportItems!Textbox6.Value= from formula

Answer (score 1):

1. If TextBox40.Value = 0 then "else" value of IIf() function will always #Error (because dividing by zero). I used Val() function to compare your value to zero, not to text. If the TextBox40.Value is equal "abc" or " " (space) or "" (empty string) then Val(TextBox40.Value) is zero too.
2. 2nd and 3rd arguments of IIf() function are results depending of 1st argument, your 2nd argument looks wrong.
3. IIf() function **calculates all arguments** before returns a result, so the 3rd argument (where may be dividing by zero), can give you #Error in result. Better is  use If() function.
4. Better than use FormatNumber() function is formatting of field in Tablix -- the code is clearer.

The expression should be (imho)

```
=If(Val(ReportItems!Textbox40.Value) = 0,  
    0.00, 
    Val(ReportItems!TotalQty.Value) / Val(ReportItems!Textbox40.Value) * 100
   )
```